# Node server: is it safe to put security credentials in npm scripts?

Tags: node.js

Often credentials are required for NodeJs server, e.g. express session key. Since environment variables can be supplied in npm scripts, is it considered a good practice to put the credentials there?

For example(in `package.json`):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "EXPRESS_SESSION_KEY=mysessionkey node server server/index.js",
}
```

So when I do `npm start` the credentials are also supplied.

P.S. Git repository is private so `package.json` is not likely to leak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not safe.

Even if git repository is private and `package.json` is not publicly available, this `package.json` file with sensitive information is available to all developers -- whoever has authority to access the git repository would be able to access the key, which is a big problem -- more people access the key, more risks.

To fix the security issue, my suggestion is using 2 keys, one for development & test, one for production. In `package.json`, development key is set, so that developers can easily clone code and launch the program:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "DEV_KEY=devsessionkey node server server/index.js",
}
```

In the code where `KEY` is used, `PROD_KEY` (key for production) would be checked and used first. `DEV_KEY` is used only if there is no `PROD_KEY`:

```
var key = process.env.PROD_KEY ? process.env.PROD_KEY : process.env.DEV_KEY;
```

When DevOps engineer deploy  the code, he/she will set environment variable `PROD_KEY` in operating system and then launch the program. By this way, only specific DevOps engineer know the production key, which makes it much safer.